# Sequence space and completeness

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Consider the following $c_0=\{(x_n)\in\mathbb{R}|\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = 0\}$ with norm $\|\|_{\infty}.$ I am trying to see why  $c_0$ is complete with supremum-norm. Here is my attempt:

Let $(x_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $c_0.$ For convenience sake we can write $$x_n=(x_{1}^n,x_{2}^n,\dots).$$ Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Since $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, there exits a positive integer $n_0$ such that $$ \|x_m-x_p\|_{\infty}<\epsilon \ \ \text{for all} \ \ m,p\geq 0$$ which means $$|x_{i}^m-x_{i}^p|<\text{sup}|x_{i}^m-x_{i}^p|<\epsilon \ \ \text{for all}\ \ i=1,2,\dots.$$ This shows that for fixed $i$,  $(x_{i}^n)$ is a Cauchy sequence of complex or real number. Since $\mathbb C$ (or $\mathbb R$) is complete so it must converge to some $y_i\in\mathbb C$ (or $\mathbb R$) , that is,  $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_{i}^n=y_i.$ Let $y=(y_1,y_2,\dots)$ and this means $$|x_{n}-y|<\epsilon$$  To finish the proof, it remains to show that $y\in c_0,$ that is, $\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n=0.$  It seems yes but I did not see how I can argue for that. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each sequence $$x_n=(x_{1}^n,x_{2}^n,\dots)$$ converges to $0$, i.e. $\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} x_{i}^n = 0$ for all $n$. So to show that $\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} y_i = 0$, use that

$$|y_i| \leq |y_i-x_{i}^{n}|+|x_{i}^{n}|$$

and justify that how $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_{i}^n = y_i$, given $\varepsilon >0$ exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > n_0$ implies $|y_i-x_{i}^{n}|< \dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Also as $\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} x_{i}^n = 0$ imply that exists $i_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $i > i_0$ implies $|x_{i}^{n}|< \dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Take $i_1 \geq  \max\{n_0, i_0\}$, then

$$|y_i| \leq |y_i-x_{i}^{n}|+|x_{i}^{n}|<2 \dfrac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon.$$

for all $i,n>i_1$.

Comment: llovemath, thank you for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: llovemath, I have a related question if you do not mind

Comment: Feel free, can ask

Comment: Thank you for your response. Need to clear that this is not a homework assignment or something  for grade just to see the details once in my life. My aim, to show that $c_{00}=\{(x_n)\colon \{n\colon   x_n\neq 0\}$ is dense in $c_0$. Starting with $y=(y_n)\in c_0$ and we will find a sequence in $x=(x^n)\in c_{00}$ such that $(x^n)\to y$ as $n\to \infty$, Now, pick a sequence like $x^1=(y_1,0,0,\dots)$ and $x^2=(y_1,y_2,0,\dots), \dots$. Again, clearly, $(x_n)\to y$ as $n\to \infty$,   Is that correct ? still some details are missing. Right?

Comment: yes! $c_{00}$ is the space of sequences which are eventually null, i.e $x_n=0$ for $n>n_0$, see that for the sequence you built $|| x^i -y ||_{\infty} = \sup_{n>i} | y_n | \rightarrow 0$ ($y \in c_0$ !), therefore $x^n \rightarrow y$.

Comment: llovemath, I notice that and i deleted my comment. Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome, good studies!

Comment: llovemath, we will end it by saying that $c_0$ is the completion for $c_{00}$ by defining the identity map $T\colon c_{00}\to c_0$ by $T(x)=x$

Comment: This is the definition of completion, look https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Completion

Comment: I know but we have $c_{00}$ is dense as subspace in $c_0$ and $c_0$ is complete. Am I missing something ?

Comment: $ T(c_{00}) = c_{00} \subset c_0$ is a dense subespace of $c_0$, then $c_0$ is the completion of $c_{00}$, you already have everything you need.